# FDT: Execute a command line command when compiling

Tags: actionscript-3, command-line, fdt

Can I somehow execute the following line in command line when I am compiling my AS3 application in FDT? If so, how do I set it up in FDT?

```
python add-advanced-telemetry.py Application.swf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the FDT Ant [tutorial](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FDT_Ant_Tasks) and [docs](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/FDT_Ant_Tasks).